# Remote printing with user authentication

Tags: printer, authentication, network-printer

I saw in one company how an employee sent documents to print from her computer, then went to a printer in another room, swiped an ID card (probably RFID) on it and it immediately printed the documents.

With what means can such technology be realized?

Comment: Likely NFC, like it's mentioned in this example: https://manuals.konicaminolta.eu/bizhub-C658-C558-C458-C368-C308-C258-UD/EN/contents/id08-_102039718.html

Comment: That is technology used in comprehensive business printers, not consumer printers or entry level businesses printers

Answer (score 1):

> I saw in one company how an employee sent documents to print from her computer, then went to a printer in another room, swiped an ID card (probably RFID) on it and it immediately printed the documents.
>
> With what means can such technology be realized?

The print job is sent to a central server that accepts jobs in some standard protocol (e.g. IPP or LPR); the OS includes the username as part of the print job and the server sorts it into a queue.

The printer's firmware often supports talking to a specific print server either built-in or as an installable "app" that communicates to the server, asking it to verify PIN codes or RFID/NFC cards and then to push the queued print jobs to the printer.